# Detecting the block under the block an entity is standing on

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I'm attempting to build a datapack, and I need to know the block at `@e[tag=relevantMob] ~ ~-2 ~` (The block under the block the relevantMob is standing on).

Is there an easy and compact way to get that information?

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out a way to do it.

`execute as @e[tag=relevantMob] at @s if block ~ ~-2 ~ <blockID> run <function>`

- `execute` is a function that controls the conditions another function runs under.
- `as @e[tag=relevantMob]` causes each relevant mob (and no other entities) to continue running the rest of the execute function.
- `at @s` makes every mob running the command calculate the function's relative coordinates from their location.
- `if block ~ ~-2 ~ <blockID>` tests the block two blocks below the mob's location. If the block at `~ ~-2 ~` matches `<blockID>` the command contiues
- finally, `run <function>` causes each relevant mob for whom the block below the block they're standing matches the specified block to perform the desiered behavior.

Comment: It's not a clean, easily expandable way of doing it. I would preferred being able to throw it in a predicate. But it works for the purpose I needed it for (a wither apparently doesn't correctly calculate the block its standing on, so I needed another way of knowing what block that was).

Comment: You can try to change the `anchored` value of the execute command. You can align the command from the feet or eyes of the target. There is also the possibility to use predicates, you can use `execute if predicate` or build it into your target selector `@a[predicate=`.

Comment: I'm flumaxed; not in how to call a predicate, but in how to structure the predicate.json to evaluate whether `@e[revelantMob] ~ ~-2 ~` is a particular block. I tried both `anchored eyes` and `anchored feet` but they didn't help my particular case: it just passed the buck by moving the question from `~ ~-2 ~` to `~ ~-4 ~`.

`if block ~ ~-2 ~ <block>` isn't pretty especially chained together, but it functions.